# How to stop the execution of a function inside agenda's job?

Tags: node.js, jobs, agenda

I have an agenda job, that every 1 day invokes stockSyncServices.startSync() function.
I need to be able send request to my rest api endpoint, and stop executing the function startSync() in request handler. I tried invoke agenda.cancel() - but it's just remove the job from db, and the function is still running.

```
agenda.define('sync', { concurrency: 1 }, async () => {
  await stockSyncServices.startSync('full')
})
```

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? I'm having the exact same problem